# What are drawbacks of installing outdoor sediment filters this way?

Tags: plumbing, water, filter

On the far left is incoming water pipe split into 2 flexible(?) pipes where each goes to the inlet of each of the filters. Outlet of both filters are joint to each others with a Tee connector at the center. Water coming out from both filters goes out through the center output of the Tee.

On one hand, I think it's good idea due to standard 10inch filters are being used here which I think kind of underwhelmed for outdoor POE filter, so it helps with filtering load by having 2 filters doing a shared job at the same time and also prevents water flow slow-down when one of the filters gets heavily clogged over time. On the other hand, I'm not sure if there's drawback or pitfall I fail to see which makes this kind of setup a bad practice

[image: two 10 inch filters]

Comment: I don't see any draw back as long as the filters are installed correctly with the input at the ends and the output in the center. The second filter may have been added to reduce the pressure drop as you suggested.

Comment: Are you super sure you never have frost/freeze problems in your area?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common setup to get high flow from smaller, cheaper filters. Two 10 gpm filters can be used to effectively get 20 gpm overall flow.

In this particular install the flex pipes, mix of galvanized and brass parts, and lack of shut-off valves and pressure gauges screams amateur installation to me, but I don't see anything that prevents it from working.

Comment: I particularly enjoy the "reduce size to use a flex hose" on a main water entry point as an amateurish hack - yeesh. "I put in a restriction here, I'd better add another filter while leaving the restriction in place!" Clear filter housings in the sunlight will never cause an algae problem, either, right?